# Web: is the convention "//mywebsite.com/mypage" with "//" a standard?

Tags: protocols, standards

Explanation for people who don't know: this syntax means to Firefox : "use the same protocol than the one the page uses". So if the page is `https` and the link (or image) is `//mywebsite.com/myimage.png` Firefox will try to download it this way: `https://mywebsite.com/myimage.png`
(Edit my question if I'm wrong I don't want to say lies).

I'm wondering: **is this a standard and all other Webbrowsers know it or if it's just something recent**?

I'm sorry but I can't find the right words when googling for it ("convention" - "https" - "//" and so on don't give good results)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which defines the URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), which is the superset of URLs and URNs, is ambiguous. Appendix A, which defines the syntax, does not show the scheme as optional, but section 5.3, which covers reconstructing a URI, *does* show the scheme as optional.

That said, it's better for security purposes if you are explicit as to which scheme is used, to prevent the possibility of sensitive information being accidentally sent in the clear.

Comment: That's interesting, but in most of the cases, information (like images, links and son on) could be sent no matter which protocol is used (sorry for my English). There are a very few exception I should take care of, but 98% of the website should be able to ignore the protocole and I find this "thing" = ("//mysite.com" very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The inventor of the web, Tim Berners-Lee, has invented these slashes as well, but they have no practical use. He even [apologized to the public](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8306631.stm) for them.

Comment: They are needed if you include scripts from another site which both supports HTTP and HTTPS. An example is jQuery hosted by Google.

Comment: Well, they are needed because of how it is designed. Paths are allowed to start with a double '/', but only if there's an authority (domain) before it. So the path posted by the OP is actually a relative path, but including a domain name. You need the slashes in that case, so the browser knows that the part behind it is indeed the autority part of an url, and not the path. But I do admit, that this comment should have been the answer, and the answer itself should have been a comment.